# Find the prime factorisation of $6500$ and $1120$, and write down, in factorised form, $\gcd(6500, 1120)$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(6500, 1120)$.

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

(i) Find the prime factorisation of $6500$, and of $1120$.

What is the typical way to go about this? Just using common divisibility rules? That's what I did. I'm not sure if there's a more structured way that I should be doing this, since it could be more difficult depending on the number? The above seem to be easy cases.

$65 \times 100 = 6500$

$13 \times 5 \times 25 \times 4 = 6500$

$13 \times 5 \times 5^2 \times 2^2 = 6500$

$13 \times 5^3 \times 2^2 = 6500$

$1120 = 112 \times 10$

$= 66 \times 2 \times 5 \times 2$

$= 6 \times 11 \times 2^2 \times 5$

$= 3 \times 11 \times 2^3 \times 5$

(ii) Hence write down, in factorised form, $gcd(6500, 1120)$ and $lcm(6500, 1120)$.

For GCD we just selected the highest powers of the numbers that are common to both? So it would be $\gcd(6500, 1120) = 5^3 \times 13 \times 2^3$?

And I think for LCM we take the lowest powers of each number? So it would be $\operatorname{lcm}(6500, 1120) = 5 \times 2^2$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Vice versa, and the lcm is $2^5\cdot 5^3\cdot 7\cdot 13$. You have to collect all the primes that appear in one of the numbers if you determine the lcm.

Comment: For $\gcd$: Is $13$ common to both?  I don't see it in your factorization of $1120$.  Does $5^3$ divide $1120$?  A greatest common divisor has to *divide* the numbers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a slight error in the prime factorisations.

$$6500=2^2\cdot5^3\cdot13\\1120=2^5\cdot5\cdot7$$ Hence we have $$\gcd(6500,1120)=2^2\cdot5\\\operatorname{lcm}(6500,1120)=2^5\cdot5^3\cdot7\cdot13$$ The key is gcd:min(powers) and lcm:max(powers)

Comment: And another difference is that the lcm does does not only select the powers of numbers that are common to both factorizations, but also those that are not? For instance you selected $13$ and $7$ for lcm, which is only part of the factorization of one of either $6500$ or $1120$?

Comment: @Wyuw Yes, precisely. Basically, for the lcm, choose the *most* factors/powers that exist in *either* integer.

Answer (score 2):

One can do the gcd without factoring first. Oh, $$ \operatorname{lcm}(a,b) = \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}  $$

$$ \frac{ 6500 }{ 1120 } = 5 +  \frac{ 900 }{ 1120 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1120 }{ 900 } = 1 +  \frac{ 220 }{ 900 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 900 }{ 220 } = 4 +  \frac{ 20 }{ 220 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 220 }{ 20 } = 11 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 20 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 & & 5 & & 1 & & 4 & & 11 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 5 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 6 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 29 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 325 }{ 56 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 325 \cdot 5 - 56 \cdot 29 = 1 $$

$$  \gcd( 6500, 1120 ) = 20  $$
 $$ 6500 \cdot 5 - 1120 \cdot 29 = 20 $$